# How do you obtain a connected (staircase looking) representation of the scaling and wavelet coefficients in Python

Tags: wavelets

How do you obtain a connected (staircase looking) representation of the scaling and wavelet coefficients instead of the unconnected result in the image below? It looks nicer in Matlab than in Python?

[image]

```
import pywt
import numpy as np
import pylab

def get_smooth_func():
    time = np.linspace(1,40,1000)
    freq = 500
    freqs = 8000
    return np.sin(2*np.pi*freq/freqs*time)

def concat_coeffs(A):
    T = A[0]
    for i in range(1, len(A)-1):
        T = np.append(T, A[i])
    return T

def draw():
    X = get_smooth_func()
    A = pywt.wavedec(X, 'db8', pywt.MODES.ppd, level=4)
    C = concat_coeffs(A)

    pylab.figure()
    pylab.semilogy(C, '-')
    pylab.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    draw()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot the absolute value.

```
pylab.semilogy(abs(C), '-')
```

[image]